# create-react-native npm start hangs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-native-app

After a successful create-react-native I tried to initialize the project with npm start. Even after 2 hours it doesn't finish loading. With the basic example is has finished a couple of time after waiting, but when I added the code with something more advanced it never finishes. I use npm 4.2.0 and node 7.10.0. I was not able to find out what npm start does. Does it has to download a lot? If so, I might know why it never finishes, because I'm in some remote place in India with very crappy internet.

```
sudo npm start --verbose
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm verb cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node',
npm verb cli   '/usr/local/bin/npm',
npm verb cli   'start',
npm verb cli   '--verbose' ]
npm info using npm@4.2.0
npm info using node@v7.10.0
npm verb run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
npm info lifecycle cameraTest@0.1.0~prestart: cameraTest@0.1.0
npm info lifecycle cameraTest@0.1.0~start: cameraTest@0.1.0

> cameraTest@0.1.0 start /home/piepongwong/Programming/reactNativeEx/cameraTest
> react-native-scripts start

9:35:47 PM: Starting packager...
```

.... hangs forever

Answer (score 0):

I have found an open issue on the [create-react-native-app github](https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/issues/234).

Running `sudo sysctl -w fs.inotify.max_user_watches=10000` before `npm start` speeds up the process.